# send file using default bluetooth application in android

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, file-transfer

I want to send a file from my phone to other phone using my Android application. The File is of type ".Xcard". I want to make use of the default Bluetooth Application provided by the android environment. That is, when I click on send , the default application chooser should open and then I should be able to send the File to other device bu selecting the device. 
How should I do it? The file may or may not be empty

I have tried the following code but its not working. I get a toast message saying :File was not sent"

```
f = File.createTempFile("card", ".Xcard", getCacheDir());
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(fw);
w.write("hello my name is neeraj"); 
w.close();

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("*/*");
i.putExtra(i.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivity(i);
```

Please help me out, I am kind of Stuck

Answer (score 0):

From the API docs:

> public abstract File getCacheDir ()
>
> Returns the absolute path to the **application specific** cache directory on the filesystem.

(emphasis mine)

The directory returned by `getCacheDir()` is only readable by your application, use `getExternalCacheDir()` instead.