# Declaring MIME type for a "custom file" that is to be Sent via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-manifest, mime-types, intentfilter

I really need help in solving this issue:

I am developing an application to transfer a file from my application to other phone using Blue-tooth. When I wanted to transfer an image file, the part of my code went as follows:

```
     intent.setType("image/*");
     i.putExtra(i.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
     //here uri has the URI of the image that I want to send.
```

And the android manifest File went as Follows:

```
 <intent-filter>
            
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    
       <data android:scheme="file" />
       <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
       <data android:host="*" />
            
            
 </intent-filter>
```

And code worked fine. Now my question is :
Similarly I want to send a file that is created by the following line:

```
   f = File.createTempFile("card", ".XCard", getExternalCacheDir());
```

The name of the file would be something like this:

```
   card12434247.Xcard
```

Now what modifications are required in the code that I posted above?
How should I write the mimeType in the intent-filter?

what should be the line:

```
  intent.setType(...)?
```

How should I modify it so that bluetooth will be able to handle this file

```
  xyz.Xcard ??
```

How should I declare the custom mime type that will be required to send my file to be sent via Blue-tooth?

Comment: some other questions regarding the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413498/blue-tooth-file-not-sent-error 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432338/send-file-using-default-bluetooth-application-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the file in the bluetooth directory, it worked for me.

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/html");

File f = new File(root + "/bluetooth/test2.html");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send page"));
```